# Encrypt existing AWS Neptune DB instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-neptune

I have created AWS Neptune DB.
However, now I want to encrypt it. As per AWS documentation, I should take snapshot and while restoring, encrypt new DB instance.

However, enabling Encryption check-box is disabled in my account.

Am I missing anything? Does it has anything to do with IAM roles/permissions?

I am trying all these steps from AWS Management Console.

Answer (score 0):

There are few instance type that does not support encryption, please check here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html#Overview.Encryption.Availability if you are using one of them.

Comment: Thanks ! 

My Neptune instance class does not belong to any of the instance classes mentioned in the link. 


DB Instance class of my existing Neptune: db.r5.large


To explain my scenario in detailed:
I have already running Neptune DB without encryption. However, I want to enable it now on this already running instance. 

As mentioned in _Limitations of Neptune Encryption section_ of  [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/encrypt.html], I have taken snapshot and trying to restore it as encrypted DB instance. While restoring, option to enable encryption is disabled.